# Error Inserting Event into Calendar with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm trying to insert events to the `calendar` from a fragment, but I keep getting an error that no activity is found to handle Intent.

Here's the error -

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT cat=[android.intent.category.APP_CALENDAR] typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/event (has extras) }

Here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Phototherapy Treatment");
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "");
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Phototherapy Treatment");

// Setting dates
Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,calDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
calDate.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);

// Make it a full day event
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);

// Make it a recurring Event                    
intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT="+Integer.valueOf(No.getText().toString())+";"
+"WKST=SU;BYDAY="+days);

// Making it private and shown as busy
 intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
 intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);

startActivity(intent);
```

---

Intent Filter

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CALENDAR" /> 
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT); and it seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: Had the same problem with a HTC Sense Android 4.0. Its annoying because the official way of doing this is with ACTION_INSERT (ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents-9

Comment: I'm using am HTC EVO with Android 4.0.3 and both INSERT and EDIT give me the ActivityNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

Calender App may not be installed in some devices. So enclose within try catch block to check.

```
Calendar startTymVar = Calendar.getInstance();
startTymVar.set(2015, 12, 31, 11, 30);

Intent calendarIntentVar = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTymVar.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "New Year")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Hav ful fun");

try
{
    startActivity(calendarIntentVar);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ErrVar)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Install Calender App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already know the information which it looks like you do you do not need to launch the calendar app, simply just insert the event into the database [see adding events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

Also looking at the docs `APP_CALENDAR` is only used with `ACTION_MAIN` not `ACTION_INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any activity that resolves this intent

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant for Android 11 and above devices, that on the top of steps mentioned in [Common Intents - Add Event](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#AddEvent), we have to add the intent in the `<queries>` block in the Android Manifest file.

Do note that adding an `<intent-filter>` on Activity which launches the calendar intent won't work as it adds that Activity as a receiver of such intents, but rather adding following snippet in manifest file does the trick:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

For me this trick worked for my Android 11 device, and it was already working fine for devices before that!

Answer (score 0):

There is not App to handle this Intent.
But it's not possible. Android phone will be carry a Calendar app.

Maybe something wrong with that app. Maybe update it will fix this.
(I updated it. Then the problem is gone.)