# Starting Calendar Activity

Tags: android, android-calendar

I was simply trying to launch `Calendar Activity` from my `Activity`. I have the following code in my `Button OnClickListener`:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/"));  
startActivity(calIntent);
```

But when I click the `Button`, my device hangs and then I have to force close the not responding app.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?  Is it ICS or newer?

Comment: Android 4.0 API level 14

Answer (score 1):

This is because the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) content Uri varies for different versions(API levels) of android. Try this code to get the calendar Uri for respective API level.

```
/*
  * Determines if it's a pre 2.1 or a 2.2 calendar Uri, and returns the Uri
  */
 private String getCalendarUriBase(Context con) {
     String calendarUriBase = null;
     Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
     Cursor managedCursor = null;
     try {
         managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // eat
     }

     if (managedCursor != null) {
         calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
     } else {
         calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
         try {
             managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             // statement to print the stacktrace
         }

         if (managedCursor != null) {
             calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
         }

     }

     return calendarUriBase;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal CalendarOrganizer class, they changed how calendar can be access from ice cream sandwich, in fact before ice cream sandwich it is recommended to use their online services for updating calendar since the google calendar might be changed or not even installed.

**Edit**: 
I learned that I needed to handle intent problems but also that some phones on ice cream sandwich will crash from Intent.ACTION_INSERT but not from Intent.ACTION_EDIT. Therefor I've updated my implementation. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9926830/969325) for a solution.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;

public class CalendarOrganizer {
    private final static int ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID = 14;
    /**
     * Creates a calendar intent going from startTime to endTime
     * @param startTime
     * @param endTime
     * @param context
     * @return true if the intent can be handled and was started, 
     * false if the intent can't be handled
     */
    public static boolean createEvent(long startTime, long endTime, String title, String description, 
            String location, boolean isAllDay, Context context) {
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID) {
            // all SDK below ice cream sandwich
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
            intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("eventLocation", location);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", isAllDay);
//          intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");

            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // ice cream sandwich and above
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
            intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
            intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY , isAllDay);
            intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);

//          intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10") 
            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me (using > v4):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
Intent calIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INSERT", uri)
    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
startActivity(calIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, ICS calendar intents are documented here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me

No need to create activity in manifest.

Will work with all android Platforms.

Will show you calender view of current month

```
            long epoch = new Date.getTime();
            Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            builder.appendPath("time");
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, epoch);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .setData(builder.build());
            startActivity(intent);
```