# insert event to calendar using intent

Tags: android

I know this has been asked previously in this forum, but I tried everything written here and still nothing works for me. What I want to do is to insert an event to the calendar. Since there are several calendar applications on my device, I want to enable the user to choose which calendar application should contain the new event, similar to what happens when the user attempts to view a location using a map application (the user can select whether to activate google maps, the internet, ...). For this reason, I have to use an Intent.

BTW, I'm aware that inserting new events to the calendar using Intents is allowed only on devices with SDK version 14 or higher. My device has an API level of 15, so it supports the calendar API.

Here's my code:

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calendarIntent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "title");
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "address");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, cal.getTime().getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, cal.getTime().getTime());
ctx.startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

I get this exception:

```
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.applicat.meuchedet/com.applicat.meuchedet.MainScreenActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.android.calendar/events (has extras) }
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.android.calendar/events (has extras) }
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1535)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1387)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.applicat.meuchedet.Screen.startActivity(Screen.java:433)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.applicat.meuchedet.CalendarAppointmentScheduler.writeAppointmentToCalendar(CalendarAppointmentScheduler.java:137)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.applicat.meuchedet.MainScreenActivity.onCreate(MainScreenActivity.java:258)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
02-04 17:55:23.957: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     ... 11 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx

Comment: Do you have the calendar app installed? The error is indicating that nothing exists to handle the intent.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You caught ActivityNotFoundException because any activity can't handle your action.

Instead using **Intent.ACTION_INSERT** try to do like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, strTitle);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                    startDateMillis);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                    endDateMillis);
intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, false);// periodicity
            intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,strDescription));
```

You can check in developer documentation for other attributes.

Comment: I think Yvan is pointing you in the right direction after seeing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926830/error-inserting-event-into-calendar-with-intent Apparently some phones don't honor the ACTION_INSERT and instead require the ACTION_EDIT. I don't think you need to use the setType line he has but I could be wrong

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. Do you know perhaps why is it necessary to use the setType code line?

Comment: can we also pass reminders information for this event through intent ??

Answer (score 10):

Insert an Event like this

```java
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);

    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
     .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
     .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, 
         beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
     .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, 
         endTime.getTimeInMillis())
     .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
     .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
     .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
     .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
     .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");

    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: its working for me. Set Begin and End time properly.

Comment: can we also pass reminders information for this event through intent ??

Answer (score 2):

From the developers documentation here is the way you can add the event to the Calendar, opening the Calendar apps chooser:

```
    fun addEvent(title: String, location: String, begin: Long, end: Long) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).apply {
        data = Events.CONTENT_URI
        putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
        putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
        putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, begin)
        putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, end)
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

You can specify various event details using extras defined.
The key point is `intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null` which will always return null from the Android API 30. So you need to add the `intent-filter` for the activity that you are using with the `INSERT` action and the specified mime type.

```
<activity ...>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Data URI** = `Events.CONTENT_URI`

**MIME Type** = `"vnd.android.cursor.dir/event"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as it checks first if there is **available apps** that can handle this intent.

```
    fun addToCalenderAction(ctx: Context, session: ItemSession) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).apply {
        data = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI
        putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, session.title ?: "AA")
        putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, session.location
                ?: "Egypt, ALex, ST23")
        putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, parseTimeOfFirebase(session.startTime
                ?: "2021-05-31T19:56:22.636+0000"))
        putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, parseTimeOfFirebase(endTime
                ?: "2021-05-31T21:56:22.636+0000"))

    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(ctx.packageManager) != null) {
        ctx.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: session is object that hold some data, you can use your own data

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant for Android 11 and above devices, that on the top of steps mentioned in [Common Intents - Add Event](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#AddEvent), we have to add the intent in the `<queries>` block in the Android Manifest file.

Do note that adding an `<intent-filter>` on Activity which launches the calendar intent won't work as it adds that Activity as a receiver of such intents, but rather adding following snippet in manifest file does the trick:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

For me this trick worked for my Android 11 device, and it was already working fine for devices before that!